# MySQL - Modify datetime columns based on additional datetime columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a rough time figuring out how to title this, but here's an explanation...

I have two tables

Table #1:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id  |        start        |         end         | duration |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  | 2013-10-01 09:00:00 | 2013-10-01 09:30:00 |    30    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  2  | 2013-10-02 10:00:00 | 2013-10-02 10:30:00 |    30    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| int |      datetime       |       datetime      |   int    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table #2:

```
---------------------------------------------------
| id  |        start        |         end         |
---------------------------------------------------
|  3  | 2013-10-01 09:00:00 | 2013-10-01 17:00:00 |
---------------------------------------------------
|  4  | 2013-10-02 09:00:00 | 2013-10-02 17:00:00 |
---------------------------------------------------
| int |      datetime       |       datetime      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the all records from table #2 match any table #1 rows that fall on the same date and within the same datetime and modify the result set by removing the times from table #1...

An example result would be...

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| table2id  |        start        |         end         |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     3     | 2013-10-01 09:30:00 | 2013-10-01 17:00:00 |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     4     | 2013-10-02 09:00:00 | 2013-10-02 10:00:00 |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     4     | 2013-10-02 10:30:00 | 2013-10-02 17:00:00 |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What ties a table #1 row to a table #2 row? Is it the start time?

Comment: And what if `table#1` contains several time intervals for same `table#2` date?

Comment: I've modified my question to be more clear, there is another fk in my actual database that ties the tables together (just an int column), other then that nothing else ties them together.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't be sure this *logic* would be correct, something like this might be close to what you're looking for:

```
UPDATE tbl2
SET start = (SELECT end FROM tbl1 WHERE start = tbl2.start)
```

It's not terribly clear how these two tables relate. However, `id` **clearly** doesn't. The only two values that match in your example are the `start` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table2.id, Table1.end_date , Table2.end_date 
FROM table1 AS Table1, table2 AS Table2
WHERE 
    Table1.start_date >= Table2.start_date 
    AND Table1.end_date <= Table2.end_date
UNION 
SELECT Table2.id, Table2.start_date , Table1.start_date 
FROM table1 AS Table1, table2 AS Table2
WHERE 
    Table1.start_date >= Table2.start_date 
    AND Table1.end_date <= Table2.end_date
```

this works but will give you an extra record with identical `start` and `end` that you have to manually delete

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| table2id  |        start        |         end         |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     3     | 2013-10-01 09:30:00 | 2013-10-01 17:00:00 |
|     4     | 2013-10-02 10:30:00 | 2013-10-02 17:00:00 |
|     3     | 2013-10-01 09:00:00 | 2013-10-01 09:00:00 | --> Extra Record
|     4     | 2013-10-02 09:00:00 | 2013-10-02 10:00:00 |
```